# How to retrieve data from all keys in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Now what I am trying to do is to get all user names from all keys.How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
    }
 }
  @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
   }
});
```

Here you datasnapshot is at `users` node then you use the for loop to iterate inside the direct children and get the names in your database.

Comment: It worked, Thank u so much

Comment: no problem, happy coding :D